# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound not playing except when I step over

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm writing an alarm clock app and I need to have the user select the chime to wake up to. I have a UITableView with a list of my sounds and when the user taps a sound I want it to play.

However, my sounds do not play unless I *step over the call* to AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (or if I put a breakpoint on the call to AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID which triggers after I hear the sound).

I had a theory that this was a main thread issue so I used performSelectorOnMainThread:

```
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(playWakeUpSound)
                               withObject:nil
                            waitUntilDone:true];
```

but that didn't help. (The value of waitUntilDone doesn't seem to matter.)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142568/sound-plays-in-iphone-simulator-with-breakpoint-but-fails-to-play-without-break) was promising but I checked and I'm only calling my method once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a guess, since I don't know what is in playWakeUpSound. If you are using AVAudioPlayer within that call and ARC, it might be because it is getting released. Store the instance of AVAudioPlayer as a member of the class and it should play.

```
@interface MyClass 
{
    AVAudioPlayer *player;
}

@end
```

Then in the implementation:

```
@implementation MyClass

- (void)playWakeUpSound {
    // Assuming name and extension is set somewhere.
    NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:extension]];

    NSError* error = nil;

    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    } else  {
        [player play];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: that was exactly it. I was ARC'd. Funny, I'm using the Apple SoundEffect.m sample code and I put NSLog's into the play and dealloc method and they were called in the right order! Thanks for the quick answer.